# How can I only take the cell out of a prompt without the whole file path?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script in which I'm processing data in 2 different workbooks. One is wbVendor and one is wbImport.
The code is written in a user form in wbImport.
A part of the code is to prompt the user to click in a cell in wbVendor. I then need the column of this selected cell. The problem now is that it takes the cell with the whole path of the workbook. So instead of taking just *$B$10* it takes *'[2018 ARA Product Listing (Airline Price).xlsx]Active Parts w Detail'!$B$10*

The code I'm using for this task is as followed:

```
wbVendor.Activate
wsVendor.Activate

Set CellPN = wsVendor.Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="Click in a cell which contains the part number in the vendors file.", Type:=8)

CellPN.Select
ColumnPN = CellPN.Column
```

When I then execute this code the following error message appears:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Select method of Range class failed.

For a better understanding I have attached a picture of the prompt in which the cell with the whole file name is in.

Thank you already for your help. I really appreciate it!!
[Print Screen Cell Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNBW7.png)

Comment: Does `ColumnPN` not contain the column number you're after?

Comment: What about `CellPN.Address`? Won't that work? Also, another option, I guess the input box "freezes" the execution of code until user select a cell in `wbVendor`. So, maybe `ActiveCell.Address` would not work? Maybe that would take only `$B$10`. Hav you tried?

Comment: Thank you for you comments.
I forgot to tell you that an error occurs. I just added it to my question. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to achieve here but the following should work:

```
wbVendor.Activate
wsVendor.Activate

Set CellPN = wsVendor.Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="Click in a cell which contains the part number in the vendors file.", Type:=8)

CellPN.Parent.Parent.Activate   'Activate the workbook of CellPN
CellPN.Parent.Select            'Select the worksheet of CellPN
CellPN.Select                   'Select CellPN

ColumnPN = CellPN.Column

AddressPN = CellPN.Address
```

The error you're seeing is due to you selecting a cell on a different sheet and/or workbook.

`AddressPN` should contain the address of `CellPN` as text.

Comment: Hi CLR. Thank you for your answer. What dimensions do the different variables have to be? I have CellPN As Range and ColumnPN As Long. This produces a run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Sorry I mean 1004: Select method of Worksheet class failed.

Comment: `AddressPN` should be a string.

Comment: Perhaps try changing `CellPN.Parent.Select` to `CellPN.Parent.Activate` ?

Comment: Tried that. Now another error pops up. 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Ok. Just found out that the line `CellPN.Select` isn't even needed. Now it works just fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To directly address the question at hand:

```
wbVendor.Activate
wsVendor.Activate 'assuming this is the worksheet contained in the workbook above,
                  'the line above is redundant and not necessary

Dim cellPN as string
cellPN = wsVendor.Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="Click in a cell which contains the part number in the vendors file.", Type:=8)

Dim result() as String
result = Split(CellPN, "!")

ColumnPN = wsVendor.Range(result(1)).Column
```

The `Split` function will allow you to break up the string returned by your InputBox function at the bang (!) which is the delimiter between the file name/worksheet and the actual cell reference. This will return an array of 2 strings, the first `result(0)` is the file name/worksheet, the second `result(1)` is the actual cell reference.

From there, you can ask the `Worksheet.Range()` function to return the `.Column` of the cell reference you provide.

Though you probably want to do some reading around here on how and why you should avoid `.Activate` and `.Select` pretty much at all cost.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now a new problem pops up. In the line where the Column number is defined now run-time error 9 occurs which is "Subscript out of range".

Comment: Type `?result(0)` and `?result(1)` in the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G) in the VBE. What results do you get? `?result(1)` should return the actual cell address you're after. If you get, for example, "$B$10", you'll have to use some string formatting to reformat it to "B:10".

Comment: For some reason the `InputBox` takes the value of the cell and not the address even though the address is shown when you click in the cell. So when I enter `?result(0)` it shows the value which is in the cell.

Comment: Ah! That means the method of selecting the cell won't work as you (and I) imagined. I'd suggest [CLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982112/2344413)'s  approach instead since his `AddressPN` will give you the actual cell address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim ColumnPN As Long
Dim CellPN As Range
Dim wsVendor As Worksheet
Dim wb as Workbook

wbName = Application.GetOpenFilename
If wbName <> False Then
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbName)
End If

Set wsVendor = wb.Sheets(1)

wsVendor.Activate

Set CellPN = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a Cell", Type:=8)

ColumnPN = wsVendor.Range(CellPN.Address).Column
```

Comment: Hi Irene G. This code causes an error 9: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: I didn’t caused an error for me... how have you defined your worksheet wsVendor? I’ll add some code on how I did it...

Comment: Maybe you need to add a reference to your workbook too

Comment: I let the user choose the workbook with `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`

Comment: I edited the code with a prompt dialog and wb reference... hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In order to `Select` a range; the worksheet on which the range resides must be active.  The means the the workbook containing that Sheet must also be active:

```
Sub PickaCell()
    Dim w As Workbook, s As Worksheet, CellPN As Range
    Set CellPN = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Click in a cell which contains the part number in the vendors file.", Type:=8)
    Set s = CellPN.Parent
    Set w = s.Parent

    w.Activate
    s.Select
    CellPN.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you all for your help. Now my code works perfectly. For those who are interested this is the final code:

```
wbVendor.Activate
wsVendor.Activate

Set CellPN = wsVendor.Application.InputBox _
    (prompt:="Click in a cell which contains the part number in the vendors file.", Type:=8)

CellPN.Parent.Parent.Activate   'Activate the workbook of CellPN
CellPN.Parent.Activate          'Select the worksheet of CellPN

ColumnPN = CellPN.Column
```

Thanks again.

Cheers,
Dominic